# Questions marked as Duplicates where original question had been deleted?

Tags: discussion

What happens when a question is marked as duplicate then the original question is deleted.

As an example I am referring to this question

[Can i prevent/restrict standard user from installing/unistalling software in ubuntu 12.04 desktop? [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/q/317738/107450)

Does the system detect such questions for review or do we just end up with questions with a dead link to now non-existent questions?

Comment: Related: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13678/is-there-a-mechanism-to-remove-marked-as-duplicate-when-the-original-question?cb=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The deleted question is still there so it does not break things but it does look funny.

I suggest that [Can I prevent/restrict standard users from installing/uninstalling software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317738/can-i-prevent-restrict-standard-user-from-installing-unistalling-software-in-ubu) needs to be re-opened. I voted to re-open it. Not saying it will not be closed again for another reason.

Comment: "The deleted question is still there" <-- only for 10k+ rep users. ;)