# Is there a mechanism to remove "marked as duplicate" when the original question is deleted?

Tags: discussion

I've found this question:

[Add a new target into rules debian file](https://askubuntu.com/q/337473/32239)

which is marked as a duplicate of:

[How to specify a control file in dh_gencontrol?](https://askubuntu.com/q/337504/32239)

But it turns out to be a deleted question.

Should the first one be reopened? Is there a mechanism that could prevent such situation? Because to me without the original question it makes no sense to leave the "marked as duplicate".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this case I have reopened the question. There has since been a feature put in place that prevents duplicate targets from being deleted so we shouldn't have to worry about it anymore.

Comment: Good to know, thanks.